# CentOs x86_64 not getting IP in from windows7 machine via data connector, works fine with Office LAN

Tags: networking, centos, virtualbox

CentOS  VirtualBox
Can anyone tell me the required settings to establish connection? I need to establish a connection with another VM too, so the network is set as a Bridged adapter.

Running:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

results in:

> Network is unreachable error

This is the output of `ifconfig`:

[image: result of ifconfig]

Answer (score 1):

You have no IP address on your network adapter; assuming that you are running DHCP and that the VM's network is bridged, you should be able to perform:
`ifup eth0` on the command line.

It might be worth checking the relevant config file (in this case probably `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and ensuring `onboot` is set to `yes`.

Failing that, it might be worth checking `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to see if every marries up correctly.